# Topology, continuous mapping help!!

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity

Give an example of a continuous mapping 
$$f:X  \to  Y; \ \ (X,\ Y\ \text{metric})$$
 for which there exists an open subset $U \subset X$
such that 
$$f(U)=\{\ y \in Y \ \mid \ \exists x \in U: f(x)=y\ \}$$
 is not open?

Comment: I know that f is continous iff the preimage of f is open in Y and a subset of Y is open in X?

Comment: It is a little hard to parse your question.

Comment: I edited your question. Please make sure it still reflects what you are asking. I fixed your wrong definition of $f(U)$ and added the criterion that $U$ should be open, otherwise any identity map and a non-open $U$ would give you an example.

Answer (score 2):

A map $f\colon X\to Y$ is continuous, if for any open subset $U\subseteq Y$, the set $f^{-1}(U) = \{x\in X|f(x)\in U\}\subseteq X$ is open in $X$. Now consider $\mathbb{R}$ as a topological space with the standard topology. And define a map
$$
f\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\\
x\mapsto 5$$
Can you show that a) $f$ is continuous and b) satisfies the property you're looking for?

Comment: f^-1(U)={x∈X|f(x)∈U} ?

Comment: and do you show it is continous by using open balls? and showing that the intersection is not empty perhaps?

Comment: yes, the $Y$ was a typo.

Comment: Was i correct in saying you have to use open balls? how would i start?

Comment: Calculate $f^{-1}(U)$ for some open subsets of $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, there are only two possibilities how $f^{-1}(U)$ might look like.

Comment: I dont understand lol :(

Comment: Let $U=B_r(5)$, then $f^{-1}(U)=\mathbb{R}$ (check this) and $\mathbb{R}$ is open. What happens if we choose $V\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, such that $5\not\in V$?

Comment: U=Bε(5)? B is a element of 5?

Comment: If v subset of R such that 5 not an element of V, would that show that R is not open and hence a contridiction?

Comment: also how would I check " f^-1(U)=R (check this) and R is open"